# how to use $ and * at the same level in a spec

Tags: json, jolt

I am new to jolt and whilst i like lots of it one thing thats really hurting me right now is how to use **`*`** and **`$`** at the same level in a spec. I have the following desired input and output. But try as i might i cannot seem to transform both the list of  action ids (there are the **`"1"`** and **`"2"`** into attribute values and move the list of action data associated with the id into a sub attribute.

Input

```json
{
  "Attr1": "Attr1_data",
  "Actions": {
    "1": [
      "Action data 1 line 1",
      "Action data 1 line 2",
      "Action data 1 line 3"
    ],
    "2": [
      "Action data 2 line 1",
      "Action data 2 line 2",
      "Action data 2 line 3"
    ]
  },
  "Attr2": "Attr2_data"
}
```

Desired

```json
{
  "Attr1": "Attr1_data",
  "Action": [
    {
      "id" : "1",
      "data" : [
        "Action data 1 line 1",
        "Action data 1 line 2",
        "Action data 1 line 3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id" : "2",
      "data" : [
        "Action data 2 line 1",
        "Action data 2 line 2",
        "Action data 2 line 3"
      ]
    }

  ],
  "Attr2": "Attr2_data"
}
```

using the following spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation" : "shift",
    "spec":  {
      "Actions": {
        "*" : {
          "$": "Action[].id"
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

I can generate

```json
{
  "Attr1": "Attr1_data",
  "Action": [
    {
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2"
    }
  ],
  "Attr2": "Attr2_data"
}
```

But try as i might i cannot seem to copy the data lines in to a new data attribute.

Can anyone pls point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert yours to the following transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*s": { // represents a tag(of an object/array/attribute) with a trailing letter "s". The reason of this reform is to be able use "Action" as the key of the inner array without repeatedly writing it.
        "*": {
          "$": "&(2,1)[#2].id", // "$" looks one level up and copies the tag name, &(2,1) goes two levels up the tree and pick the first piece separated by asterisk, [#2] goes two level up in order to reach the level of "Actions" array to combine the subelements distributed from that level in arrayic manner with "Action"(&(2,1)) label, and the leaf node "id" stands for tag of the current attribute 
          "*": "&(2,1)[#2].data"
        }
      },
      "*": "&" // the rest of the attributes(/objects/arrays) other than "Actions"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, i think i was almost at that point 3 days ago, my sanity is restored.